# Difference between svg and g element?

Tags: svg

What is the difference between using a `svg` (nested inside the svg) and a `g` element?

Both of these can be used to group together elements into one unit. When should I use a nested `svg` element and when should I go for a `g` element?

Also there is the `symbol` element that does not render, then you refer to use it using the `use` element, but you can also put the code inside the `defs` element instead of using a `symbol` element. So what is the difference between `symbol` and having the code in `defs` and when should I use either one and how do I know under when to use which?

| Element | Type | Visibility | Notable attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `svg` | Container, structural | Renders | `preserveAspectRatio`, `viewBox`, `zoomAndPan` |
| `g` | Container, structural | Renders | `transform` |
| `defs` | Container, structural | Invisible, use its children with the `use` element | `transform` |
| `symbol` | Container, structural | Invisible, use with the `use` element | `preserveAspectRatio`, `viewBox` |
| `use` | Graphics, referencing, structural | Renders, refers to another element | `transform` |

Comment: doesn't https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement answer your symbol questions?

Comment: The SVG specification also covers <svg> and <g> elements so what is it about the description in the specification of how they work that's unclear?